# Download manager making app freeze

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using DownloadManager to download image file. Now if the DownloadManager is turned off, i am checking that programtically and displaying a Toast message to user asking them to enable DownloadManager  for downloading. Everything is working fine is Android 6.0. But in Android 4.3 Samsung duos,when i turn off DM,my condition returns true and Toast message i am able to show. Now if i go to settings and enable the DM and come back to app to download a file,my app gets freezed.Please help

Comment: Also to add one more thing,if i enable the download manager from disabled state and clear the cache/data,then my download is happening in the app smoothly for 4.3 handset

Comment: Can you please share your code which is responsible for downloading image through DownloadManager ?